# Tkinter: subpanel is not showing up in the main window

Tags: python, tkinter

- Closing this question as Part 1 was my primary problem at the time*
  I'm writing a small app to show menu buttons on a left side panel and the functionality on the right.

**Part 1:** The main app windows shows up fine (first image) and the AppDownloader() works by itself (second image). The goal is for AppDownloader() frame to show up in the right-hand panel. **ANSWER**: **The call to draw the panel wasn't in the `__init__`. Adding the existing `draw_downloader_pane()` method to `AppDownloader.__init__()` fixed this part of the issue. The `app_downloader.py` code is at the bottom. *I'm still working on the Download pane widget placements, separate from this.*

**Part 2:** However, it's still not switching between panes, even after double-checking that the `AppTransform.__init__()` method didn't have the same problem as Part 1.

I've checked my `master` references to make sure they're calling the correct frames. I think the `tkraise()` is acting on the right objects. When I click the buttons in the main app window, I get the following debugging info, but it doesn't switch the pages:

[image]

*UPDATE: revised AppDownloader() code with Part 1 solution*

`app_main.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Misc
import customtkinter as ctk
## my modules
from app_downloader import AppDownloader
from app_transform import AppTransform
from app_toolkit import CTK_DARK_MODE, CTK_COLOR_SCHEME, PADX, PADY, COLOR_THEME
# log formatting
from my_logging import setup_logging 

logger = setup_logging('app_main.py')

ctk.set_appearance_mode(CTK_DARK_MODE)
ctk.set_default_color_theme(CTK_COLOR_SCHEME)
              
class AppMain(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctk.CTk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        WIDTH = 680
        HEIGHT = 600
        MENU_WIDTH = 280
        self.title("Switch Frames")
        self.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.left_master = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, **COLOR_THEME, width=MENU_WIDTH, corner_radius=0)
        self.left_master.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, expand=False, padx=PADX, pady=PADY)
        self.right_master = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, **COLOR_THEME, corner_radius=0)
        self.right_master.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def draw_left_menu(self):
        row_i=1
        menu_heading = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.left_master, text="Activity Menu", font=("Roboto Medium", -16))
        menu_heading.grid(row=row_i, column=0,  padx=PADX, pady=PADY)    
        row_i += 1
        
        BTN_PADX = 9
        BTN_PADY = 8
        BTN_IPADY = 5
        self.menu_buttons = [
            {'btn_name': 'download', 'btn_label': 'Download Shelf', 'frame_name': 'AppDownloader'},
            {'btn_name': 'transform', 'btn_label': 'Transform Data', 'frame_name': 'AppTransform'},
            {'btn_name': 'updates', 'btn_label': 'Find Updates (Unimplemented)', 'frame_name': None},
            {'btn_name': 'ids', 'btn_label': 'Find Book IDs (Unimplemented)', 'frame_name': None},
            {'btn_name': 'save',  'btn_label': 'Save Results (Unimplemented)', 'frame_name': None},
            {'btn_name': 'quit', 'btn_label': 'Quit App', 'frame_name': None}, 
            ]
        for data in self.menu_buttons:
            str_var = tk.StringVar()
            str_var.set(data['btn_label'])
            btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.left_master, textvariable=str_var, 
                                corner_radius=6, width=130)
            btn._text_label.configure(wraplength=140)
            data['btn_object'] = btn
            if 'quit' in data['btn_label']:
                btn.grid(row=row_i, column=0, padx=BTN_PADX, pady=(40,0), ipady=BTN_IPADY)
            else:    
                btn.grid(row=row_i, column=0, padx=BTN_PADX, pady=BTN_PADY, ipady=BTN_IPADY)
            row_i += 1

    def draw_right_container(self):
        self.frames = {}
        self.right_container = ctk.CTkFrame(self.right_master)
        self.right_container.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        for F in (AppDownloader, AppTransform):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=self.right_container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.pack(side="top", fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def show_frame(self, frame_name):
        frame = self.frames[frame_name]
        ## debug statement      
        logger.debug(f"{frame}")  
        frame.tkraise()

    def configure_buttons(self):   
        self.menu_buttons[0]['btn_object'].configure(command=lambda:self.show_frame('AppDownloader'))
        self.menu_buttons[1]['btn_object'].configure(command=lambda:self.show_frame('AppTransform'))

    def start_app(self):    
        self.draw_left_menu()
        self.draw_right_container()
        self.configure_buttons()


a = AppMain()
a.start_app()
a.mainloop()
```

Here's the correct`AppDownloader` setup:
`app_downloader.py`

```
class AppDownloader(ctk.CTkFrame, InitValues):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, **COLOR_THEME)
        InitValues.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0, uniform='auto')
        # init code here
        self.draw_downloader_pane()

    # functionality methods snipped

    def draw_downloader_pane(self):
        self.frame_body = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.parent, **COLOR_THEME)
        banner_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.parent, **COLOR_THEME)
        banner_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, expand=True, padx=PADX, pady=PADY)
        banner = ctk.CTkLabel(master=banner_frame, text="Download and Save Files", 
                              **COLOR_THEME)
        banner.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, expand=True, padx=PADX, pady=PADY)
        self.draw_frame_body()
        self.frame_body.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=PADX)
```

Comment: The long black rectangle at the right of first image are actually the combined instances of `AppDownloader` (top half) and `AppTransform` (bottom half).  If you set the two frames to different colors, you can identify them easily.

Comment: Oh... so do I need to do a check if the other frames exists and then do a `self.frames[page_name].forget()` for each of them if do?

Comment: I did try moving the .pack() statement outside the `for` loop and after the `AppDownloader` call. That didn't help like I hoped it might. It still shows an empty frame.

Comment: There are several questions on switching frames, like [switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter).

Comment: Use `grid()` instead of `pack()` on the frames inside `right_container`.

Comment: It changed something, but didn't bring the window up. Used `frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro4zS.png

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you.  I rewrite both `AppDownloader` and `AppTransform` to have only a label inside them, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the inspiration (and by extension, confirming I have that part right)! I'll play around with it and report back.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the solution I found for Part 1 not showing up. Next part is the switching between panes.

Comment: Why do you use `self.parent` as the master of `self.frame_body` and `banner_frame` inside `draw_downloader_pane()`? Should `self` be used instead? Did you read the link on switching frame I posted in my past comment, it tells you how to switch frames using `grid()`.

Comment: When I change it to just `self` and call `AppDownloader` from `app_downloader.py` , it draws a blank window. I use `root = ctk.CTk()    download_frame = AppDownloader(root, root)`.

Comment: Is the grid() method the ONLY way to switch between frames? Is there no way for the pack() method to work with tkraise()? If it's a definitive no, I'd love to know. Otw, I'm researching it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: *I've updated this Answer to show the final solution that resolved both parts of the question. Since I'm just a hobbyist, it took me a while to get my frame stack to work for me. I think my problem (like many others) was I was using `master=self.parent` in my `AppDownloader` and `AppTransform` class. But they're their own widgets/frames, so they should only render on `self`.

As for the `tkraise()`, I just couldn't get it to work. There was no `.forget()` in use when I was trying this method. It would switch to a new frame but it never switched to the old frame. So I went with a `.pack() -> .forget() -> .pack()` work flow.

Here is my final implementation that works!

```py
class BookshelfApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctk.CTk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        WIDTH = 680
        HEIGHT = 600
        MENU_WIDTH = 280
        self.title("Bookshelf Tools")
        self.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.color_theme = COLOR_THEME
        self.lFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, **self.color_theme, width=MENU_WIDTH, corner_radius=0)
        self.lFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, expand=False, padx=PADX, pady=PADY)
        self.rFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, **self.color_theme, corner_radius=0)
        self.rFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, anchor=tk.NW, padx=PADX, pady=PADY)
        self.frames = {}
        self.D_name = 'AppDownloader'
        self.T_name = 'AppTransform'
        for F in (AppDownloader, AppTransform):
            frame_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=self.rFrame, controller=self)
            self.frames[frame_name] = frame
            frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.Y, expand=True)
        self.current_frame = self.download_frame
        self.show_frame(self.current_frame)
        self.draw_menu_buttons()

    def raise_current_frame(self):
        frame = self.frames[self.current_frame]
        frame.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.rFrame.update_idletasks()

    def show_frame(self, new_frame):
        if self.current_frame not in new_frame:
            old_frame = self.frames[self.current_frame]
            old_frame.forget()
            self.current_frame = new_frame
        self.raise_current_frame()

    def draw_menu_buttons(self):
        BTN_PADX = 9
        BTN_PADY = 8
        BTN_IPADY = 5
        btn_args = {'corner_radius': 6, 'width': 130}

        row_i = 1
        menu_heading = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.lFrame, text="Activity Menu", font=("Roboto Medium", -16))
        menu_heading.grid(row=row_i, column=0,  padx=PADX, pady=PADY)    
        row_i += 1
        btn_1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.lFrame, text='Download Shelf', **btn_args, 
                              command=lambda:self.show_frame(self.D_name))
        btn_1._text_label.configure(wraplength=140)
        btn_2 = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.lFrame, text='Transform Data', **btn_args, 
                              command=lambda:self.show_frame(self.T_name))
        btn_2._text_label.configure(wraplength=140)
        btn_quit = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.lFrame, text='Quit', **btn_args, 
                                 command=lambda:self.quit_app)
        btn_quit._text_label.configure(wraplength=140)

        btn_1.grid(row=row_i, column=0, padx=BTN_PADX, pady=BTN_PADY, ipady=BTN_IPADY)
        row_i += 1
        btn_2.grid(row=row_i, column=0, padx=BTN_PADX, pady=BTN_PADY, ipady=BTN_IPADY)
        row_i += 1
        btn_quit.grid(row=row_i, column=0, padx=BTN_PADX, pady=BTN_PADY, ipady=BTN_IPADY)
```

In my class initialization, I'm using `master=self` because the Class is already a Frame widget itself instead of `master=self.parent`. Then I made a new frame `self.frame_body` and drew it with `.grid()`. Everything else will be in `master=self.frame_body`:

```py
class AppDownloader(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        self.color_theme = COLOR_THEME
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, **self.color_theme)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform='auto')
        banner = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, text="Download and Save Files", **self.color_theme) 
        banner.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        self.frame_body = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, **self.color_theme)
        self.frame_body.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news")
        ### ...
```